# Do I assume Equality of variances for a paired t test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

I’m doing a paired t test and was just wondering if I assume equality of the variance and why I would or wouldn’t

Answer (score 4):

There's no such assumption needed.

Inference is focused on the population distribution of the pair-differences. The population of paired observations reduces to a population of single pair-differences, and so we deal with a one sample test (carried out on the sample pair-differences).

Which is to say, once you take the pair-differences there's only one variance, not two.

Comment: Expanding on this, paired testing ends up being a one-sample test.

Comment: @Dave yes, it's probably worth being explicit in the answer